# Disable WordPress "PHP Deprecated:" messages from debug.log

Tags: wordpress

I have searched & tried various solutions to this problem, none of them work.

It looks like WordPress ignores the following and logs Deprecated messages anyway:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
```

My **php.ini**:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
```

My **wp-config.php**:

```
<?php
define( 'WP_CACHE', true );
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);

...

define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
```

Plugins are spamming my **debug.log** file with `PHP Deprecated: ...` log messages. Several GB generated each day. Makes **debug.log** unusable.

I report to Plugin developers, but some do not fix in timely manner. I cannot fix myself, as Plugin update overwrite my changes.

What is the solution to disable these?

**Server:**

- Running Bitnami/Wordpress on AWS Lightsail (2gb 2vcpu)
- Linux 5.10.0-25-cloud-amd64 x86_64
- PHP ver.8.2.10

Comment: The solution here https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/239501/suppress-deprecated-notices worked pretty well for me. Following the instructions, I created a php file "suppress-deprecation.php" with the content indicated. Note it removes other non-critical error types as well.

Comment: The root cause: The WordPress ecosystem of software is not yet fully compatible with php 8.2. For production you're better off, as of Oct 2023, using 8.1. Pester your plugin developers to get their code updated to 8.2. And use a staging site to test it.

Comment: @CKMacLeod Thanks, this worked: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/413264/236453

Comment: You're quite welcome, Interesting. Maybe I should have been more specific: The answer that worked for me was https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/398023/35923 I didn't try the alternative you chose, since the first one seemed simpler, was adequate, and I think might work in a larger variety of environments. Either way, glad you found an answer. I had debug logs exploding just like yours.

Comment: Thank you, @CKMacLeod for that link! That made me creating a plugin to control the must-use plugin and the detailed error level from within the admin panel. See my answer for details. Credits to you and the OP from your link.

Comment: @volkerschulz You're quite welcome, though credit really belongs to the OP who did the  thinking involved. I'll try your plugin and may fiddle with it some.

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE**
I've created a [WordPress plugin](https://github.com/volkerschulz/WordPress-Error-Reporting) to add, remove and control the MU plugin from the comfort of your admin panel.

**Original post**
No matter what you set for `error_reporting()` inside the `wp-config.php` and no matter what's in the `php.ini`, it will be overwritten by WordPress in `function wp_debug_mode()` (in `wp-includes/load.php` called by `wp-settings.php`) as follows:

```
if ( WP_DEBUG ) {
    error_reporting( E_ALL );
    //...
} else {
    error_reporting( E_CORE_ERROR | E_CORE_WARNING | E_COMPILE_ERROR | E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_USER_ERROR | E_USER_WARNING | E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR );
}
```

You could, of course, change `E_ALL` to `E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED` inside `wp-includes/load.php`, but that is (eventually) going to be overwritten with WordPress updates.

Another (persistent) option is to use a `must use plugin` to reset `error_reporting` (again). This however **will not** mute deprecation warnings resulting from the WordPress core. To do that anyway, create the directory `wp-content/mu-plugins` if it doesn't exist. Inside that directory add `__error_reporting.php` with the following contents:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
```

Must use plugins will be loaded in alphabetical order before all other plugins (hence the `__` prefix).